# navigation Link still remains active on change react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have two navigation buttons that utilize the  tag of react-router-dom.
The problem I am facing is when I shift from the first button to the second button, the first button still remains active.

In my situation, I have a `runs` button and `input` button
The `runs` button is in active state, but when the `input` button is clicked, the run button is still active

Here is my snippet showing the navigation tabs :
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

```
<div className = "navigation-tabs">

      <NavLink to={`/tasks/${task}`} activeStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#0022ff', color: '#FFF' }}>
        Runs
      </NavLink>
      <NavLink to={`/tasks/${task}/input`} activeStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#0022ff', color: '#FFF' }}>
        Input
      </NavLink>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React router dom will treat `/tasks/${task}` and `/tasks/${task}/input` as the same path. To change this, add `exact` as  an attribute to your navlink tags as follows:

```
<div className = "navigation-tabs">

      <NavLink exact to={`/tasks/${task}`} activeStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#0022ff', color: '#FFF' }}>
        Runs
      </NavLink>
      <NavLink to={`/tasks/${task}/input`} activeStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#0022ff', color: '#FFF' }}>
        Input
      </NavLink>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `exact` property can fix this. Because your URL like "/task/5" and "/task/5/input", in this case, router check the first part of URL so this two URL starts with "/tasks/5" and this why your link always active

```
<NavLink to={`/tasks/${task}`} exact activeStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#0022ff', color: '#FFF' }}>
    Runs
  </NavLink>
```